# searching in text file word list and check all the words that start with each letter I input

Tags: python-3.x

So far I got this ...

```
with open('d:\word_list.txt', 'r') as inF: 
b = input('Enter word: ') 
for letter in b: 
 for item in inF: 
  if item.startswith(letter): 
   print(item)
```

If I type "zucaritas", this code only prints those words begining in "z" and not the other letters, the "u", the "c", etc. I want to check all the words from the list that start with each letter I want to type.
What can I do? By the way, I'm a beginner in python. Thanks

Comment: Is this your actual code? You seem to be missing a quote mark on the `input` line.

Comment: _"print only those words begining in "z" and not the other letters"_. Do you mean, that's what you want to happen, and it's not happening? Or that's what's happening, but you don't want that to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating through `inF` the first time exhausts it, and it can't be iterated through again. So the loop will only execute for the first letter in `b`.

You can get a fresh file object by opening the file repeatedly, for each letter in `b`:

```
b = input('Enter word: ') 
for letter in b: 
 with open('d:\word_list.txt', 'r') as inF: 
  for item in inF: 
   if item.startswith(letter): 
    print(item)
```

Alternatively, you can manually rewind the file object to its beginning state with [`seek`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek):

```
with open('d:\word_list.txt', 'r') as inF: 
 b = input('Enter word: ') 
 for letter in b: 
  inF.seek(0)
  for item in inF: 
   if item.startswith(letter): 
    print(item)
```

Comment: @Kevin: it is not necessary to iterate over the file multiple times, you could [pass a tuple to startwith()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26501386/4279).

Answer (score 0):

### Node JS script

```
var fs = require("fs");
var letter = process.argv[2];

var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("./letters/" + letter + ".txt");


fs.createReadStream("./word_list.txt").on("data", function(chunk){
    var words = chunk.toString().split("\n");
    words.forEach(function(word){
        var firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
        if(firstLetter == letter || firstLetter == letter.toUpperCase()){
            console.log(firstLetter);
            writeStream.write(word + "\n");
            console.log("wrote " + word);
        }else{

        }



    });
});
```

you can call this like `node your_script_name.js b` to save all the words that begin with `b` to a file called `letters/b.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can print all words that start with any letter from a given word in a single pass through the word list from the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
letters = tuple(input('Enter word: ')) # startswith() can work with a tuple
with open(r'd:\word_list.txt') as file:
    for word in file:
        if word.startswith(letters): # if word starts with any of the letters
           print(word, end='')
```